# Does a bootstrap class need to be placed in a div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For example what is the difference between

```
<div class="page-header">
            <h1>Example Page Header</h1>
</div>
```

and just writing:

```
<h1>Example Page Header</h1>
```

on the tutorial on w3Schools it says to place the `"page-header"`class in a `div`element but does not say why. It seems unnecessary , is there a reason for this?

Comment: Look at the two in this fiddle, see a difference? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/2/

Answer (score 1):

As the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#page-header) state:

The page-header class is:

> A simple shell for an `h1` to appropriately space out and segment
>   sections of content on a page. It can utilize the `h1`'s default `small`
>   element, as well as most other components (with additional styles).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily in a div, for example.

```
<nav class="page-header">
nav
</nav>
```

Or

```
<header class="page-header">
header
</header>
```